# Impossible to select kernel in visual studio code, findKernel crashed : 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I am using Visual Studio Code with the Jupyter extension (ms-toolsai.jupyter) version 2021.8.1054968649, I am connecting to a container over ssh (so I use both Remote - Container and Remote - SSH). For various reasons I cannot use the default local version of the Jupyter, I have to run on an existing Jupyter notebook.
It used to work, but now the extension cannot find any kernel (should be an option on the far right) :
[image: Kernel selection]

When I try to start the first cell it proposes me to select a kernel, but there is none :
[image: Kernel selection 2]

After looking into the log it seems that I get an error 503

```
Error 2021-07-27 17:23:09: findKernel crashed [t [Error]: Invalid response: 503 Service Unavailable
    at /home_local/user/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.8.1054968649/out/client/node_modules/@jupyterlab/services.js:3:492374
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async m.getRunningKernels (/home_local/user/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.8.1054968649/out/client/extension.js:90:227410)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async y.listKernels (/home_local/user/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.8.1054968649/out/client/extension.js:90:468689)] {
  response: N [Response] {
    size: 0,
    timeout: 0,
    [Symbol(Body internals)]: { body: [PassThrough], disturbed: false, error: null },
    [Symbol(Response internals)]: {
      url: 'http://distant_adress:8888/api/kernels?1627399389810',
      status: 503,
      statusText: 'Service Unavailable',
      headers: [I [Headers]],
      counter: 0
    }
  }
}
```

Where distant_adress is the address that is given by the command `jupyter notebook list` and `user` is simply my username on linux.

I already tried :

- Restarting jupyter and changing the address : does not work
- Since I also have a port forward, go to the local address on my computer and not on the server : does not work (however jupyter on my machine works well with the port forward)

Answer (score 7):

I just ran into the same problem. Not a satisfying answer, but uninstalling the jupyter extension, reloading vs code, and reinstalling fixed it for me :/

Comment: Did you uninstall it both remotely and locally ?

Answer (score 0):

Updating the Jupyter extension, Did the job for me. I am not sure if it will work for others.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).